# Is quantum game theory reducible to classical game theory?

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, quantum-mechanics, algorithmic-game-theory, quantum-computation

**Modnote:** This question was manually migrated (closed and [crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/135782/25494)) to MathOverflow by request of the OP.

---

> [Quantum game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_game_theory) is an extension of classical game theory to the quantum domain. It differs from classical game theory in three primary ways:
>
> 1. Superposed initial states,
> 2. Quantum entanglement of initial states,
> 3. Superposition of strategies to be used on the initial states.
>
> This theory is based on the physics of information much like quantum computing.

I wondered if QGT is reducible to classical GT, i.e., whether *any* quantum game can be transformed to *some* classical game.

---

<sup>*Related issues:* To prove the *opposite*, would we need a space-like separation between players' acts? Would one need [Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem)? Should players' acts be outside each other's light-cones? Do we have to appeal to physics (e.g., QM itself *and/or* GR)? Would we need [counterfactual definiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_definiteness)? Would we need to dismiss [superdeterminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism)? Are, some or all, such issues *already* covered (by *hidden* assumptions) in classical game theory or even economics?</sup>

---

Can anyone perhaps point to relevant literature that *specifically* deals with this (the title) question?

Comment: I never understood the point of quantum GT. Maybe, [this](https://theoryclass.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/my-beef-with-quantum-games/) is useful.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks for the link. Do you mean that you wonder like me, or perhaps that you assume/believe/think/know that QGT has no field of application? Or both?

Comment: What I know about QGT is mostly from aXriv surveys. My impression is that the people in this field are from a different planet and what they write about classic GT isn't GT as I know it. So I think it is very hard o relate to.

Comment: This question was too old to migrate and has been reposted to MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/135782/25494